# Is it possible for a nonnormal magic square to have the same magic constant as a normal magic square of the same order?

Tags: matrices, recreational-mathematics, magic-square

I've been programming some quick and fast solutions to 4x4 magic square problems, and I've come across an assumption I've been using: The only squares with the magic constant 34 are the normal 4x4 magic squares.

Is this assumption correct? Can it be generalized to magic squares of any order?

Comment: What limitations are you imposing?  What if we replace numbers according to the map $x \mapsto 3x-17$?  Does that count?

Comment: I'm mostly referring to the nonnormal magic squares with integer entries (not necessarily consecutive integers), though I'm interested in any extension or generalization because I find this an interesting topic to think about

Comment: My example converts a normal magic square into one with integer entries, but not consecutive, and some negative, but still with the magic constant $34$.  Is that acceptable, or are you expecting all of the entries to be non-negative (but not necessarily distinct)?

Comment: I apologize, I made an arithmetic error checking your example initially and thus assumed it was an arbitrary mapping and not a counterexample to my assumption, but it is definitely within my constraints and simply invalidates my assumption. Thank you for the help!